# Google Fast Button - Breaks swipe events?

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I'm using a swipe component (www.swipejs.com), and inside my "slides", I have a couple of links that use Google's Fast Button (to prevent ghost clicks).

When I try to swipe left or right, starting the event *on* any of the links (with my finger), nothing happens.
If I start the event with my finger, *in between* any of the links, it works fine.

It seems like Google Fast Button is cancelling other touch events to bubble up, or something.
Have anyone experienced the same issue?